# kable displays different number of digits in each column

Tags: r, knitr, digits

I am using kable with the knit to Word functionality at work.  I find that I often have simple tables with counts as the first column and then a few columns with proportions.  I'd like the count column to be rounded to the nearest digit and the other columns to the nearest hundredth.  I've tried using the digits = c(0,2,2) argument within the kable() command, but it still displays two digits for the count, even though it is rounding to the nearest digit.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Can you convert the counts to `integer` type? Does that make any difference at all when printing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not see the problem here.

```
> knitr::kable(as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12), 4)), digits = c(0, 2, 2))


| V1|    V2|    V3|
|--:|-----:|-----:|
| -1|  2.11| -0.54|
|  0| -0.33|  0.95|
| -1| -1.14| -0.96|
|  0|  1.45| -0.93|
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.5 formatR_0.10.5 knitr_1.6   stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I did not have as.data.frame at the beginning.  Adding that has fixed it.  So simple.

Answer (score 1):

A quick example with `pander`:

```
> df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = runif(5), c = runif(5))
> library(pander)
> pander(df)

------------------
 a    b       c   
--- ------ -------
 1  0.5949 0.4595 

 2  0.7645 0.5012 

 3  0.7755 0.6024 

 4  0.818  0.01271

 5  0.4329 0.7588 
------------------

> panderOptions('digits', 2)
> pander(df)

--------------
 a   b     c  
--- ---- -----
 1  0.59 0.46 

 2  0.76  0.5 

 3  0.78  0.6 

 4  0.82 0.013

 5  0.43 0.76 
--------------
```

This is what you need?